# Can't Run C# Code in Xamarin Studio, Play Button Greyed Out

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

This might have a very simple answer.

I'm trying to learn C# on my Mac, so I downloaded Visual Studio for editing and Xamarin Studio to run. However, after putting in my "Hello World" code into Xamarin, I literally am unable to click the play button on the top left hand corner.

Any ideas? I thought about reinstalling, how do I uninstall Xamarin Studio? [What my code looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Yvm5.png)

Comment: Xamarin Studio on Windows is obsolete. Use Visual Studio and create a new C# console application to get started. What you did right now is meaningless.

Comment: @LexLi he said he's using both visual studio and Xamarin studio on his MAC, not on windows.

Comment: XS has been deprecated on both platforms.  What type of project did you create?

Comment: Yes I am on Mac. Re-downloading Visual Studio for Mac as XS has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Press on solution to expand it

[image]

Then select startup project by right click

[image]

If you still can't build, then you need to download Xamarin.Mac (since you're building on Mac, rather than on a mobile device) You can do that by launching installation, it will ask to re-download missing frameworks.